# Gap Between Abscissae of Conditional Convergence and Holomorphicity for Dirichlet Series

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

For a Dirichlet series, $D = \sum_n a_n n^{-s}$ we may define the abscissae, in (non-strictly) increasing order

- $\sigma_c(D) = \inf\{\sigma : D \text{ converges in } \mathrm{Re} s > \sigma \}$, the abscissa of conditional convergence,
- $\sigma_b(D) = \inf\{\sigma : D \text{ defines a bounded, holomorphic (in $s$) function in } \mathrm{Re} s > \sigma \}$, the abscissa of boundedness,
- $\sigma_u(D) = \inf\{\sigma : D \text{ converges uniformly (in $s$) in } \mathrm{Re} s > \sigma \}$, the abscissa of uniform convergence, and
- $\sigma_a(D) = \inf\{\sigma : D \text{ converges absolutely in } \mathrm{Re} s > \sigma \}$, the abscissa of absolute convergence.

H. Bohr [B1913] studies these, finding $\sigma_b(D) = \sigma_u(D)$.  He then turns to the gap $\sigma_a(D) - \sigma_u(D)$.  D. Carando and P. Sevilla-Peris [CS2014] review Bohr's methods, the result of H.F. Bohnenblust and E. Hille [BH1931] that the supremum of this gap over all $D$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, and then generalize the results.  (This gap has [previously appeared](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259285/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-abscissa-of-holomorphy-and-abscissa-of-conv) on MathOverflow.)

Is anything known about the "other" gap, $\sigma_u(D) - \sigma_c(D)$, and its relation with Bohr's gap (beyond the elementary: the sum of the two gaps is at most $1$)?

### References

[B1913] H. Bohr. Über die gleichmäßige Konvergenz Dirichletscher Reihen. *J. Reine Angew. Math.*, 143:203–211, 1913.

[BH1931] H. F. Bohnenblust and E. Hille. On the absolute convergence of Dirichlet series. *Ann. of Math.* (2), 32(3):600–622, 1931. [MR 1503020](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1503020).

[CS2014] D. Carando and P. Sevilla-Peris. On the convergence of some classes of Dirichlet series. *Actas del XII Congreso Dr. Antonio Monteiro (2013)*, :57-66, 2014.  [URL](http://inmabb-conicet.gob.ar/publicaciones/actas-del-congreso-monteiro/12/09-carando.pdf/at_download/file)

Comment: @July : I don't object to the abscissae being $\pm \infty$, but it's a fairly common exercise to show (using summation by parts) that if either is finite, $\sigma_a - \sigma_c \leq 1$.  Hardy observes this ([The General Theory of Dirichlet's Series](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Dirichlet%20Series%20de%20Hardy.pdf), Cambridge Tracts in Mathematical Physics, no. 18, p. 9 (PDF page 17)): "If [in a generalized Dirichlet series], $\lambda_n = \log n$, the maximum possible distance between the lines of convergence is $1$."

Comment: Though it may not definitely answer your question, you may be interested in the following article by Kaczorowski and Perelli : https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07630

Comment: You may find much more literature on Laplace transforms. Also using that $D(s) \Gamma(s)$ is fast decreasing then $D(s)$ is holomorphic for $\Re(s) > -K-\epsilon$ iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{-nx} - \sum_{k=0}^K b_k x^k e^{-x} = \mathcal{O}(x^{K+\epsilon})$ where $b_k = n!(-1)^n\sum_{m=0}^k D(m)\frac{(-1)^m}{(k-m)! }$